# alert() called on new window seems to be called from original page if using jQuery's methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, window.open

This is [the test case](http://jsfiddle.net/DkEBf/).

Using **JavaScript**:

```
$('.js').on('click', function () {
    var newwindow = window.open();
    newwindow.document.write('<span>test</span>');
    newwindow.document.write('<scr' + 'ipt>alert(1)</scr' + 'ipt>');
});
```

This gives the expected result: the dialog alert is showing inside the new window.

Using **jQuery**:

```
$('.jquery').on('click', function () {
    var newwindow = window.open();
    $(newwindow.document.body).append('<span>test</span>', '<scr' + 'ipt>alert(1)</scr' + 'ipt>');
});
```

The dialog alert is shown inside the main page.

Why the difference? Am I missing something here?

*This behaviour has been tested in chrome/FF/safari/IE*

**EDIT**

As pointed out by [mishik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17814584/1414562), this is due to how jQuery handles script tags, using the `globalEval` method to run scripts in the global context. So a possible workaround for using jQuery (but not fall back to the pure JavaScript method) could be to set the `newwindow` variable in the global context too and use it like that, e.g:

```
$('.jquery').on('click', function () {
    newwindow = window.open();
    $(newwindow.document.body).append('<span>test</span>','<scr' + 'ipt>newwindow.window.alert(1)</scr' + 'ipt>');
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DkEBf/2/)

Comment: +1 Is this is the reason, why people say jQuery is faster than javascript?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems like this is the way jQuery handles `<script>` tag.

`domManip` function in jQuery source code:

```
// Evaluate executable scripts on first document insertion
for ( i = 0; i < hasScripts; i++ ) {
    node = scripts[ i ];
    if ( rscriptType.test( node.type || "" ) &&
        !jQuery._data( node, "globalEval" ) && jQuery.contains( doc, node ) ) {

        if ( node.src ) {
            // Hope ajax is available...
            jQuery._evalUrl( node.src );
        } else {
            jQuery.globalEval( ( node.text || node.textContent || node.innerHTML || "" ).replace( rcleanScript, "" ) );
        }
    }
}
```

`domManip` will strip all the `<script>` elements, evaluate them in global context and then disable.

`domManip` is called by `append()` method:

```
append: function() {
    return this.domManip( arguments, function( elem ) {
```

Comment: @Neal fallback to pure JavaScript methods.

Comment: This is correct! Just testing it using: `document.body.style.display = "none";` prove this is right. I should have read the source code but i was not expecting it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Actually it doesn't seem to strip and remove the scripts, but just disable them by changing their `type` attribute and then re-enabling them after having them inserted in the DOM.